# Can a module add a line in the DNN web.config when installing it?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Recently I was creating a module to install basic things for other modules dependent of it. 
I have to make a web.config change manually in order to all modules work and I was wondering if there is any way to automate it in the module instalation proccess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  In your module's DNN Manifest file, you can add a config section.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/manifest-config-component

Example:

```
<component type="Config">
    <config>
        <configFile>web.config</configFile>
        <install>
            <configuration>
                <nodes>
                    <node path="/configuration/appSettings" action="update" key="key" collision="overwrite">
                        <add key="myCustomKey" value="123456789" />
                    </node>
                </nodes>
            </configuration>
        </install>
        <uninstall>
            <configuration>
                <node path="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='myCustomKey']" action="remove" />
            </configuration>
        </uninstall>
    </config>
</component>
```